# Graph the inequality $1<|2z-6|<2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

How to graph the inequality $1<|2z-6|<2$ in the complex plane?
My work so far is below:
I assume $z$ is complex so it can be represented as $z=a+bi$
\begin{align}
1<|2z-6|<2 \\
1<2|(a+bi)-3|<2 \\
\frac{1}{2}<|a-3+bi|<1\\
\frac{1}{2}<|a-3+bi|<1 \\
\frac{1}{2}<\sqrt{a^2-6a+9+b^2}<1 \\
\frac{-35}{4}<a^2-6a+b^2<-8 \\
\end{align}
From there I am confused.
(Note that I am assuming that $z$ is complex as the this part of a question for a complex analysis class and we are just starting to cover the basics of complex numbers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$1<|2z-6|<2 \Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{2}<|z-3|<1 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{4}<|z-3|^2<1$$

$$\frac{1}{4}<(a-3)^2+b^2<1$$

What is:

$$(a-3)^2+b^2<1?$$

and

$$(a-3)^2+b^2>1/4?$$

what about the intersection?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: think geometrically.

Divide the inequality through by $2$. Where will you find the points in the plane whose distance from $3+0i$ is between $1/2$ and $1$?